# C# back color change

Tags: c#

I just started studying C# in university and I have a problem with something. I need to make the back color change when I click one button with if-statement. My code is this:

```
BackColor = Color.Red;
if ( BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
if (BackColor == Color.Blue)
{
    BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

The problem is the back color changes to green instantly.. what should I do to make it change in the three colors? Sorry if the question is dumb.

Comment: @MichaelMontero Why does it matter?

Comment: You are lacking one `else` and you should not always begin with Red or else there can never be any variation. For animation use a timer or (arrgh) make the application wait..

Comment: change your `if...if` to `if...else if`. Or if this is a method, return immediately after the condition is fulfilled..

Comment: _"Sorry if the question is dumb."_ - a teacher of mine always said: "The dumb questions are the ones you do not ask."

Comment: you should learn about debugging and stepping through the code, it will help you a lot in the future. for example, you could easily solve this problem yourself if you knew how to debug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to understand the `if condition`s. The first if evaluates to `true` because you just assigned `Color.Red` to `BackColor` then the second if is also true because you just assigned `Color.Blue` to it.

Also if you initialize `BackColor` with `Color.Red` the first will be always true so it will be `Blue` this way. I guess you want to do this:

```
 if (BackColor == Color.Green) 
 {
     BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
 else if (BackColor == Color.Red)
 {
     BackColor = Color.Blue;
 }
 else if (BackColor == Color.Blue)
 {
     BackColor = Color.Green;
 }
```

I would suggest you to read more about [if conditions](https://www.dotnetperls.com/if). Also, like Rotem suggested, please check about [switch](https://www.dotnetperls.com/switch) too.

Comment: One may consider a `switch` clause neater in this case.

Comment: I did that :
BackColor = Color.Green;
            if (BackColor == Color.Green)
            {
                BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (BackColor == Color.Blue)
            {
                BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
and it doesn't work..

Comment: @DenislavGavrilov now whenever you run this code it will be red. you need to initialize it to `Color.Green` somewhere else. not in this code block. Maybe try the constructor to do `BackColor = Color.Green; ` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did it. Thank you very much. I will consider reading about "switch" and more about the if-statement.

Comment: @Rotem: indeed, the problem is that the color properties like `Color.Red` aren't constants

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah right, good point. Forgot about that. I guess you could work around it with c# 7.0 pattern matching but at that point it becomes much uglier than chained `if`/`else`s.

Comment: @Rotem I think using any of the two is suboptimal here. My suspicion is it is asked to be used for sake of being used. Badly crafted exercise ...

Answer (score 1):

**Applies only if the use of "if" is not mandatory:**

```
class xyz{
    private Color[] myColors = new Color[]{ Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green }
    private int colorIndex = 0;

    // BackColor also declared somewhere here ...

    private void clickHandler( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
         colorIndex = (++colorIndex)%myColors.length; 
         // ++ColorIndex is short for colorIndex = colorIndex + 1
         // % - "Remainder" => when colorIndex is 3 then 3 % 3 ( Remainder of 3 / 3 ) = 0
         // So this will increment on each click and "reset to 0" on 3, so you stay in bounds.
         BackColor = myColors[ colorIndex ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the constructor

```
BackColor = Color.Green;
```

And but this inside the onclick method

```
if (BackColor == Color.Green) 
{
    BackColor = Color.Red; 
} 
else if (BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    BackColor = Color.Blue;
} 
else if (BackColor == Color.Blue)
{ 
    BackColor = Color.Green; 
}
```

That should work for you